# jQuery array index resets to 0 when finished, how to keep the last value?

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, each

I have severals divs and an array. I insert each of the divs (id) in the aray with a function. If I apply that function to new divs, the array will start with index value 0, intead of keeping the last index value.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nQWfG/

```
assign('.firstround');
```

Assigns index values of 0, 1, 2.

```
assign('.secondround');
```

Assigns index values of 0, 1, 2 again, and I want them to be 3, 4, 5.

**EDIT**

The reason I am doing this two times is because $('.secondround') divs will be loaded time later via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a global index: http://jsfiddle.net/nQWfG/2/

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
assign('.firstround, .secondround');
```

**EDIT**

You can also add using [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
myArray.push($('#' + index));
```

instead of

```
myArray[index] = $('#' + index);
```

Comment: I think, this is only an example an he really needs the separate calls (e.g. when used in a click event handler).

Comment: I can't do that as my assign('.secondround'); will be assigned to (later) ajax loaded divs

Comment: @Alvaro, I said it was the simplest way but I had the feeling it was not gonna be what you wanted, worth a try though

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a var outside of the function to keep track of that, and increment it instead of using the index of the each function. It's the way 'each' works.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
myArray[index] = $('#' + index);
```

`index` is the index of the element in the set of elements matched by the selector.

Once you run your first selector through your function, `myArray` contains 3 elements indexed 0, 1 and 2. Next time around, you just re-assign three *new* elements to the same indices, as the selector only changed the matched elements, not their relative indices.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I would use `myArray.push()` along with `.index()` to do what I think you're trying to do:

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nQWfG/4/**

---

A better approach would be to use jQuery objects:

```
var $elements = $('.firstround, .secondround').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(index);
});

$elements.eq(1).css('background', 'red');
$elements.eq(4).css('background', 'green');​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nQWfG/6/**

Comment: I am trying to include elements loaded later via ajax to the array ('.secondround' in the example), will this solution work with those?

Comment: jQuery objects don't monitor the DOM for newly inserted elements. You'd have to call this selector after the new elements are loaded via AJAX.

Comment: So if in the first solution I apply assign('.secondround'); when ajax has finished, will it work? I can't use ajax in jsffidle.